# Screen command cannot get the parameter

Tags: bash, macos

SCREEN command cannot get parameter before reattached.

The `screen` command can start a exe_file with the following script:

`start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dm -S screen-name /path/to/exe_file
```

This exe_file could only terminate with `ctrl+c`, so I tried to write another script:

`stop.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -X -S screen-name stuff $'\003'
```

But the problem is I **must** use `screen -r screen-name` to reattach it, then `ctrl+a d` to detach it, then the stop script can actually work. If not, the exe_file won't be terminate.

System: macOS 10.14.4

Terminal: iTerm2

Comment: Can't you just send `SIGINT` to the PID of the running `exe_file` using `kill` or `killall`?

Comment: @cdarke PID could change, I don't know how to use it in a system script.

Comment: There are several ways to get the pid, and you don't need it at all with `killall`.

Answer (score 0):

## This will work:

```
screen -X -S screen-name kill
```

## Also this will work:

```
screen -X -S screen-name quit
```

Comment: Due to the program that runs in it, these two commands could only terminate the screen itself, but not that program in it. This program must be terminate by passing the parameter "ctrl+C"